# Merge 2 Pandas data frames by column without duplicates and and select which columns to be retained

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 2 pandas data frames with same structure:
DF1

```
 col1  col2 col3               col4                col5      
  Type Key Date first found    Date last found     Status
0  A     1 2020-08-11 07:28:18 2020-08-11 07:28:18 Done
1  A     2 2020-08-11 07:28:18 2020-08-12 07:28:18 In Progress
2  B     3 2020-08-11 07:28:18 2020-08-13 07:28:18 Done
3  B     4 2020-08-11 07:28:18 2020-08-13 07:28:18 In Progress
4  C     5 2020-08-11 07:28:18 2020-08-13 07:28:18 Done
```

and

DF2

```
col1  col2 col3               col4                col5      
  Type Key Date first found    Date last found     Status
0  A     1 2020-08-15 07:28:18 2020-08-15 07:28:18 Done
1  A     2 2020-08-15 07:28:18 2020-08-15 07:28:18 In Progress
2  B     3 2020-08-15 07:28:18 2020-08-15 07:28:18 Done
3  B     6 2020-08-15 07:28:18 2020-08-15 07:28:18 In Progress
4  C     7 2020-08-15 07:28:18 2020-08-15 07:28:18 Done
```

What I need to have as an end result is a data frame which takes columns 1-3 from DF1 and columns 4-5 from DF2 and not have duplicates. In case the key exists only in one of the data frames it should be recorded also in the resulting data frame e.g.:

DFResult

```
col1  col2 col3               col4                col5      
  Type Key Date first found    Date last found     Status
0  A     1 2020-08-11 07:28:18 2020-08-15 07:28:18 Done
1  A     2 2020-08-11 07:28:18 2020-08-15 07:28:18 In Progress
2  B     3 2020-08-11 07:28:18 2020-08-15 07:28:18 Done
3  B     4 2020-08-11 07:28:18 2020-08-13 07:28:18 In Progress
4  C     5 2020-08-11 07:28:18 2020-08-13 07:28:18 Done
5  B     6 2020-08-15 07:28:18 2020-08-15 07:28:18 In Progress
6  C     7 2020-08-15 07:28:18 2020-08-15 07:28:18 Done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first `inner` merge the first three columns of the dataframe (as desired) with the last two columns of the second dataframe. However, for the second datatframe, make sure to include `'Type','Key'` as those are the columns you will merge `on`.

Then `concat` this `temp` dataframe with `DF1` and `DF2` and dropt the duplicates based off the subset of `['Type','Key']` and keep the `first` value when removing duplicates. That is because you are passing the `temp` dataframe as the first dataframe in `pd.concat`

```
temp = pd.merge(DF1[['Type', 'Key', 'Date first found']],
                DF2[['Type','Key', 'Date last found', 'Status']],
                how='inner',
                on=['Type','Key'])

DFResult = pd.concat([temp,DF1,DF2]).drop_duplicates(subset=['Type','Key'], keep='first')
DFResult

Out[11]: 
  Type  Key     Date first found      Date last found       Status
0    A    1  2020-08-11 07:28:18  2020-08-15 07:28:18         Done
1    A    2  2020-08-11 07:28:18  2020-08-15 07:28:18  In Progress
2    B    3  2020-08-11 07:28:18  2020-08-15 07:28:18         Done
3    B    4  2020-08-11 07:28:18  2020-08-13 07:28:18  In Progress
4    C    5  2020-08-11 07:28:18  2020-08-13 07:28:18         Done
3    B    6  2020-08-15 07:28:18  2020-08-15 07:28:18  In Progress
4    C    7  2020-08-15 07:28:18  2020-08-15 07:28:18         Done
```